# Is the pingdom uptime monitor increasing my GA bounce rate

Tags: html, google-analytics, pingdom

I've been looking at my Google analytics account and noticed a surge in the bounce rate. Is it possible the PINGDOM uptime monitor is causing this increase? There seems to be a correlation between the two.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about Google Analytics bounce rate and is not programing related.

Answer (score 0):

That is very likely since Pingdom's uptime monitor makes a HTTP(S) call to page(s) on your website to verify that they're up. You can avoid this simply by excluding their IP addresses from being logged as visits by Google Analytics by adding them to GA's exclusion list, as documented in [the Google Analytics help pages](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I think it cant increase your bounce rate. cause analytics filtering bots, but if you sure that pingdom run analytics.js and was not filtering by default, you can add they domain/ip in custom filter (in view).

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you could check, if increased bounce rate can be credited to any traffic sources. This might already be linked to Pingdom as a referrer. You should also check with Pingdom FAQ or Support, whether they run your scripts during their measurements. E.g. [this product](https://www.pingdom.com/product/transaction-monitoring) or product feature of theirs claims to run javascripts.

If scripts are executed during measurement, then Analytics scripts are also very likely to executed, and therefore a call will be made to GA servers for your site. In this case, solutions mentioned in other responses can be used, e.g. filterin based on traffic source's domain or IP.

If scripts are not run, then you'll have to look for other reasons behind. Again, traffic source base breakdown of bounce rate could be a good place to start.